# what possible values of objectClass for Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPrincipal

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm getting the members of an Active Directory group and then checking the value of the objectClass property. It looks like they are either "user" or "group". But, I can't be sure those are the only possibilities because I am having trouble finding definitive documentation.
Short answer: do you know if that's right?
Long answer: do you know of documentation defining this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the ability to test it since we don't use the object type on my network but I would assume 'contact' is a third possibility, it's also possible to place computer objects into groups, in which case you would have a 'computer' objectClass present.  I can't think of any other possibilities but I also can't find documentation either so I can't confirm.